# Why doesn't temperature of recombination epoch coincide with Hydrogen plasma transition?

Tags: cosmology, temperature, big-bang, plasma-physics, hydrogen

The temperature of [recombination epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)) was 3000-4000K.

The temperature of [Hydorgen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen) transition to plasma is >10000K.

Shouldn't they coincide? Why not then?

Is this because of lower pressure, than on diagram? What pressure it was when recombination?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pressure of the hydrogen gas at the epoch of recombination was
$$p \sim 0.25(1+z)^3 k_B T \simeq 10^{-11}\ {\rm Pa}$$
for $z=1100$ and $T\sim 3500$ K, and where $0.25$ m$^{-3}$ is the present number density of hydrogen atoms/protons. This pressure is far to the left of the phase plot you show.

Answer (score 0):

What's more, it is true that at 3000 K, very few free electrons, and very few photons, have the necessary energy (corresponding to about 160,000 K) to ionize hydrogen.  So your question can be reframed, why does ionization happen when so few particles can do it?  The answer is, ionization allows an electron to go from very few states in the atom, to very many free states.  So each of those individual transitions has to be extremely unlikely, in order for the aggregate sum to add up to a fairly equal probability of going in either direction.  (This is also why stellar surfaces ionize at T way below 160,000 K.)

Comment: Since there are $\sim 10^9$ photons for every H atom then even if a small fraction of the photons have $E>13.6$ eV, then there are plenty of photons with the necessary energy. This is why recombination occurs at 3000 K.